# How can I manually trigger a Javascript event handler that has multiple parameters passed to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a Javascript application, I am creating an event handler during runtime based on user input, as so:

```
 $( "#someElement" ).on( "click", function( e ){
     someFunction( e, param1, param2, param3 );
 });
```

As you see, someFunction takes in additional parameters (beyond the event object) that are available at the time the event handler is created.

How can I manually trigger this event handler from outside the namespace that it was created in?  I created a "dummy" event object, and tried:

```
 $( "#someElement" ).trigger( "click", [dummyEventObj] );
```

But, that didn't work.  someFunction gets called, but param1, param2, and param3 do not exist.  Any ideas?

Comment: If `paramN` variables are available at the time you initialize the handler then they should be available when the `click` event fires.  Is there no `paramN` variables on the higher scope?

Comment: You can store the `param1 , param2,param3`  in the global context for the first time when the `someElement` is clicked and later on you can use them and pass them in trigger function . That is one way to do it . If you want to still bind by this approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that the problem was that my event handler function `someFunction` needed some additional logic to properly handle the manual event trigger.  Instead of adding more logic to the part of the function handling `click` events, I created a custom event called `navbutton`, and added logic to `someFunction` for that custom event.  I then setup a manual trigger for that custom event based on user input, and it's working great now.  So, MinusFour was correct with his/her comment: the parameters passed to `someFunction` when it was initialized were always there...it was just that the logic for handling the manual trigger properly was not.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to figure out your issue and get it working! Great job! May I suggest that you add your updated code for the future stackers can do it too?

Comment: So, basically, all I did was to create a custom event handler which takes in the same extra parameters as the `click` event handler:

Comment: @RichardBarker I created a custom event handler `navutton` which takes in the same extra parameters as the `click` event handler: `$( 'someElement' ).on( 'navbutton', function( e ){ someFunction( e, param1, param2, param3 ); });`   Then, in `someFunction`, I use a `switch` statement to apply different logic based on the event type, which I can get from `e.type` normally.  For the custom event which I manually trigger, I just create an event object as `var myEvent = {}` and then assign `myEvent.type = 'navbutton'`. I just pass myEvent with the jQuery trigger func.